# SQL Server: Error to import data with umlauts and special characters

Tags: sql-server, unicode, utf-8, import, sql-server-2014

I am trying to import this data [here](https://pxnet2.stat.fi/PXWeb/pxweb/fi/Kuntien_avainluvut/Kuntien_avainluvut__2017/kuntien_avainluvut_2017_aikasarja.px/?rxid=444223df-f91c-4479-891f-5dcd50b983d2) with special characters such as `ä` and `ö` (umlauts). When I import data in SQL Server Management Studio, I get the following error

> [image]
>
> `The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-9)'fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'. Parameter name: chars (mscorlib)`

so how can I import the data with umlauts to SSMS? What is causing the error and how to overcome it?

Comment: ensure your column type that the data is going into can support unicode.  Look for data-types prefixed with "N" like NVARCHAR or NCHAR.  Can you provide the schema for the table you're trying to import to?  You can find this by running `SELECT TABLE_NAME
 , COLUMN_NAME
 , DATA_TYPE
 , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM [information_schema].[columns]
where table_name = 'myTableName'`

Comment: @EMUEVIL I import the data from a CSV file.

Comment: Maybe silly question, but did you check the Unicode box in the General window when you made your Flat File connection? And as @EMUEVIL said, make sure your target columns are of a type that can accept unicode data (prefixed with N like NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR).

Comment: @hhh I'm not talking about the format of the CSV.  You can't import unicode data into non-unicode table columns.

Comment: You may picked wrong Locale/code page from the drop down list in the import/export wizard.